# Executar css ao carregar pagina CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de tirar a borda ao carregamento da pagina, mas apresenta  seguinte erro.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined
```

JS

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

   document.getElementsByClassName("linha").style.border= "0 none";
 });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.linha {
border: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
height: 390px;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="linha">

                <img src="imagens/camisa_1.JPG" alt="camisa1" class="imagem_teste">


    <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>

<h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
     <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já está utilizando jQuery você definir a borda assim:

```
$('.linha').css('border', '0 none');
```

Answer (score 2):

A função `getElementsByClassName` devolve uma lista de elementos que tem a classe indicada, e não apenas `1`. Pode tentar aceder o primeiro por exemplo utilizando `[0]`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("linha")[0].style.border= "0 none";
//---------------------------------------^ aqui
```

Ou se tiver vários utilizar um `for`:

```
for (let linhaHtml of document.getElementsByClassName("linha")){
    linhaHtml.style.border= "0 none";
}
```

Mas se já está a utilizar JQuery, simplifique e faça:

```
$(".linha").css("border","0 none");
```

Que funciona para 1 ou mais elementos, sem ter que diferir no código.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".linha").css("border","0 none");
});
```

```css
.linha {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
  height: 390px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linha">

  <img src="imagens/camisa_1.JPG" alt="camisa1" class="imagem_teste">


  <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>

  <h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
  <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button>

</div>
```

[Documentação para a função `getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: tem também o `querySelector()`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Correto, era outra alternativa válida, que tem até tendencia a ser mais escalável e fácil de manter, pois pode ter qualquer seletor que não apenas classe.